# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed .Find

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is a simple case of incorrect syntax and poor understanding of object, so hopefully this will be an easy fix.

I have the following variables declared globally in a separate module.

```
Public TargetWorkbook       As Workbook
Public SourceWorkbook       As Workbook
Public myWorksheet          As Worksheet
Public SourceWorksheet      As Worksheet
Public TargetWorksheet      As Worksheet
Public SettingsWorksheet    As Worksheet
```

Then, within a function, the code starts like this:

```
    Dim FoundRange As Range

    'Fields Required (Import)
    Dim RowStartField       As Long
    Dim RowCountField       As Long
    Dim RowLastField        As Long
    Dim ColStartField       As Long
    Dim ColLastField        As Long
    Dim ColCountField       As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set TargetWorksheet = TargetWorkbook.Worksheets("Fields Required")

Debug.Print TargetWorksheet.Name
Debug.Print TargetWorkbook.Name
    
    Set FoundRange = TargetWorksheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)).Find("Column Number")
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then ColumnNumberColumn = Range(FoundRange.Address).Column
        
    Set FoundRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)).Find("Report Fields")
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then FieldsColumn = Range(FoundRange.Address).Column
            
    Set FoundRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)).Find("Qunote Fields")
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then QunoteFieldColumn = Range(FoundRange.Address).Column
```

TargetWorkbook was defined in the function from which this function is called.

The problem is that I get runtime error 1004 on the line `Set FoundRange = TargetWorksheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)).Find("Column Number")`

Debug.print confirms that both TargetWorksheet and TargetWorkbook are what they should be.

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are defining `TargetWorkbook` as a variable, but there is no line in which you `Set` it

Comment: Try to change to `Range("A1:J1").Find("Column Number")`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I did set the TargetWorkbook in a previous module ('Set TargetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook'). I thought that the fact that 'debug.print TargetWorkbook.Name' gives me the correct name confirms it is still set. Is that not the case?

Comment: Without a worksheet reference `Cells(1, 1)` is on the active sheet which may not be your TargetWorksheet. Define a range `Set rng = TargetWorksheet.Range("A1:J1")` and use in all the Finds as `Set FoundRange = rng.Find()`

Comment: Also  `FoundRange.Column` is the same as `Range(FoundRange.Address).Column`.

Comment: @CDP1802 thank you, both points are helpful. What I don't understand is how is 'TargetWorksheet.Range("A1:J11")' not the same as 'TargetWorksheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10))'?